# Java - Implementing QuickSort

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm learning datastructures and algorithms. So I have tried implementing the quick sort alogorithm.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int[] arr = new int[] { 10, 16, 8, 12, 15, 6, 3, 9, 5 };

    quickSort(0, arr.length - 1, arr);
}

public static void quickSort(int start, int end, int[] arr) {

    if (start < end) {

        int partitionIndex = partition(start, end, arr);
        quickSort(start, partitionIndex - 1, arr);
        quickSort(partitionIndex+1, end, arr); // When passing partitionIndex+1 in the swap method it throws index out of bound exception

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }   

}

public static int partition(int start, int end, int[] arr) {

    int pivot = arr[end];
    int pIndex = start;

    for (int i = 0; i < end - 1; i++) {

        if (arr[i] <= pivot) {
            swap(i, pIndex, arr);
            pIndex++;
        }
    }

    swap(pIndex, end, arr);
    return pIndex;

}

private static void swap(int i, int index, int[] arr) {

    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[index]; // index out of bound exception is thrown
    arr[index] = temp;

}
```

When doing the recursive call `quickSort(partitionIndex+1, end, arr);` and in the `swap` method it is throwing `index out of bound exception`. Because there is no such index to retrieve/store the value. 
Can any one please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you tried to implement the *Lomuto partition scheme* from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme). If that's the case you have 2 errors in your code, both in the `for` loop of the `partition` method:

1. start index:

You algorithm starts every time at **0**. That is causing the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, because it swaps `pIndex` which is `array.length` at the end. If you fix this, the exception will be gone, but your sorted result will be `[3, 5, 8, 10, 12, 15, 6, 16, 9]`, which is obviously not perfectly sorted.

2. end condition:

The error here is, that the last iteration is missing every time, because your end condition is `i < end - 1` change that to `i < end` or `i <= end - 1` and you should get a perfect result:

`[3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16]`

For completion here is the fixed `partition` method and your `quickSort` method:

```java
public static void quickSort(int start, int end, int[] arr) {
    if (start < end) {
        int partitionIndex = partition(start, end, arr);
        quickSort(start, partitionIndex - 1, arr);
        quickSort(partitionIndex + 1, end, arr);
    }
}

public static int partition(int start, int end, int[] arr) {
    int pivot = arr[end];
    int pIndex = start;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < pivot) {
            swap(pIndex, i, arr);
            pIndex++;
        }
    }
    swap(pIndex, end, arr);
    return pIndex;
}
```

Comment: If i change this to i < end or i <= end - 1, i'm getting stack overflow error

Comment: Have you changed the `quickSort` method?

Comment: Not sure, where exactly to change. Could you please tell me?

Comment: `partitionIndex + 1` is required for the second recursion call.

Comment: I added the `quickSort` method to my answer, so ist complete now, except the `swap` method.

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot :)